# jQuery DataTables Bind C# System.Data.Datatable to Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, datatable

I would like to take advantage of the child row feature as demonstrated at `http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html` but I am having no joy with binding an existing System.Data.Datatable.

**HomeController.cs**

```
public DataTable GetData(string sql, string connectionString)
{
    var tbl = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        using (sqlConnection)
        {
            var sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConnection);

            using (sqlDataAdapter)
            {
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(tbl);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    return tbl;
}

var sql = "SELECT [Title], [Firstnames], [Surname], [Address1], [Address2], [Postcode], [PhoneNumber], [CustomerNumber], [System] FROM [OurDb]

using (var tbl = GetData(sql, MyConnection))
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    var rows = (from DataRow dr in tbl.Rows select tbl.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => dr[col])).ToList();

    ViewBag.AjaxDataTable = serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full",
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "ajax": "@Html.Raw(ViewBag.AjaxDataTable)",
        "columns": [
    {
        "className": 'details-control',
        "orderable": false,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": ''
    },
    { "data": "Title" },
    { "data": "Firstnames" },
    { "data": "Surname" },
    { "data": "PhoneNumber" }
],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    });

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
});

function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
'<tr>' +
    '<td>Name:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.Surname + '</td>' +
'</tr>' +
'<tr>' +
    '<td>Agreement:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.CustomerNumber + '</td>' +
'</tr>' +
'<tr>' +
    '<td>System:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.System + '</td>' +
'</tr>' +
'</table>';
}
```

Can somebody, please show me what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated :-)